# How to convert a class expression (from restriction unionOf) to a string?

Tags: sparql, jena, protege

A SPARQL query returns a result with restrictions with `allValuesFrom` and `unionOf`. I need do `concat` these values, but, when I use `bind` or `str` functions, the result is blank.

I tried `bind`, `str` and `group_concat` functions, but, all of it was unsuccessful. `Group_concat` return a blank node.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?source  ?is_succeeded_by
WHERE {
    ?source rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction . 
    ?restriction owl:onProperty j.0:isSucceededBy . 
    ?restriction owl:allValuesFrom  ?is_succeeded_by .
    FILTER (REGEX(STR(?source), 'gatw-Invoice_match'))
}
```

**Result of SPARQL query in Protegé:**

[image: Result of SPARQL query in Protegé]

Comment: do you use the SPARQL tab or the Snap SPARQL plugin?

Comment: and can you show how you tried to concat the values?

Comment: And maybe also tell me what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can hardly obtain strings like 'xxx or yyy' programmatically in Jena, 
since it is Manchester Syntax, an OWL-API native format, and it is not supported by Jena. 
Any class expression is actually b-node, there are no such builtin symbols like 'or' in raw RDF.

To represent any anonymous class expression as a string, you can use [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api), 
which is a jena-based OWL-API, and, therefore, both SPARQL and Manchester Syntax are supported there.

Here is an example based on pizza ontology:

```
    // use pizza, since no example data provided in the question:
    IRI pizza = IRI.create("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owlcs/ont-api/master/src/test/resources/ontapi/pizza.ttl");
    // get OWLOntologyManager instance from ONT-API
    OntologyManager manager = OntManagers.createONT();
    // as extended Jena model:
    OntModel model = manager.loadOntology(pizza).asGraphModel();

    // prepare query that looks like the original, but for pizza
    String txt = "SELECT DISTINCT ?source ?is_succeeded_by\n" +
            "WHERE {\n" +
            "    ?source rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction . \n" +
            "    ?restriction owl:onProperty :hasTopping . \n" +
            "    ?restriction owl:allValuesFrom  ?is_succeeded_by .\n" +
            "    FILTER (REGEX(STR(?source), 'Am'))\n" +
            "}";
    Query q = new Query();
    q.setPrefixMapping(model);
    q = QueryFactory.parse(q, txt, null, Syntax.defaultQuerySyntax);

    // from owlapi-parsers package:
    OWLObjectRenderer renderer = new ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl();
    // from ont-api (although it is a part of internal API, it is public):
    InternalObjectFactory iof = new SimpleObjectFactory(manager.getOWLDataFactory());

    // exec SPARQL query:
    try (QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model)) {
        ResultSet res = exec.execSelect();
        while (res.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = res.next();
            List<Resource> vars = Iter.asStream(qs.varNames()).map(qs::getResource).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (vars.size() != 2)
                throw new IllegalStateException("For the specified query and valid OWL must not happen");
            // Resource (Jena) -> OntCE (ONT-API) -> ONTObject (ONT-API) -> OWLClassExpression (OWL-API)
            OWLClassExpression ex = iof.getClass(vars.get(1).inModel(model).as(OntClass.class)).getOWLObject();
            // format: 'class local name' ||| 'superclass string in ManSyn'
            System.out.println(vars.get(0).getLocalName() + " ||| " + renderer.render(ex));
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
American ||| MozzarellaTopping or PeperoniSausageTopping or TomatoTopping
AmericanHot ||| HotGreenPepperTopping or JalapenoPepperTopping or MozzarellaTopping or PeperoniSausageTopping or TomatoTopping
```

Used env: ont-api:2.0.0, owl-api:5.1.11, jena-arq:3.13.1